# Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating...<UIAlertController>

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

So I have a main view which simply consists of a tableview then a second view controller called `RouteViewController` which consists of a `mapView` and a `UITextView`. I get the user's current location and if the location manager fails, then I show them an alert about it. Easy right?

But every time the alert view controller is called I get the following warning at first:

> Warning: Attempt to present UIAlertController: 0x7cb58200 on
>   "AppName".RouteViewController: 0x7e4450e0 while a presentation is in
>   progress!

The alert does appear though and I am able to cancel it and everything. Then when I go back to my table view and click on another item, I get the following warning this time:

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is
>   deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior
>   (UIAlertController: 0x7cb58200)

And just like before, the alert appears and I can even cancel it.

I have looked for solutions but none have actually being useful thus far.

**PS: I kept `locations.count > 100` in order to try simulating a scenario when the location manager might fail**

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
//  RouteViewController.swift
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class RouteViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate,   CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var routeDescriptionTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var route: Routes?
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

func updateRouteView()
{
    let routeName = "\((route?.routeName)!)"
    let routeNumber = "\((route?.routeNumber)!)"
    let routeDescription = ((route?.routeDescription)! as NSArray).componentsJoinedByString("\n")
    let routeTimes = "\((route?.routeTimes)!)"
    let routeDaysOfOperation = ((route?.routeDaysOfOperation)! as NSArray).componentsJoinedByString(", ")
    routeDescriptionTextView.text = "Route Name: \(routeName) \n\n Route Number: \(routeNumber) \n\n \(routeDescription) \n\n \(routeDaysOfOperation) \n\n \(routeTimes)"
}

func showAlertToUser(errorTitle: String, errorMessage: String)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: errorTitle, message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    updateRouteView()
    title = "\((route?.routeName)!)"

    routeDescriptionTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) // this is for the textview scrolling size

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy =  kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() // change to always if background needed
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//TODO: Make this better. I don't like the way it is at the moment.
//TODO: Make location tracker work when app is in the background

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    if (locations.count > 100)
    {
        let location = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

//TODO: Add an alert to the user for the locationManagerError
//TODO: Okay, the above TODO is partially complete.Fix the warnings received from view presentation

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
{
    showAlertToUser("Location Manager Error", errorMessage: error.localizedDescription)
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```